# Vertical align checkbox and span inside label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically align a a span and checkbox within a label tag in all browsers.

```
<div class="container">
  <label class="checbox checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span>Remember Me</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

My CSS file

```
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

label span {
  font-size: 14px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1px;
}
```

FWIW, I'm using Bootstrap 3. It looks like Bootstrap adds **4px** top margin to its checkbox, remove the top margin didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried using flexbox

Comment: if you are using bootstrap then read the Doc and use their for component http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline

Comment: @GeorgiosDimitriadis Yes I have tried using flexbox. FWIW, I'm also changing the font-size of span inside the label to 14px